# Magento2: Catalogsearch Result Page change to 1column doesnt work

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Want my search results only in 1 column. 
After updating my `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` with `layout="1column"` I got a blank site with a Error 500.

Clearing cache, deploy static files was done. (using Magento 2.2.6)

Any ideas?

File:

> /app⁩/design/⁨frontend/⁨theme/⁨Default/Magento_CatalogSearch⁩/⁨layout⁩/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.result" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::result.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- If argument's position depends on image size changeable in VDE:
                        positions:list-secondary,grid-secondary,list-actions,grid-actions,list-primary,grid-primary
                    -->
                        <argument name="positioned" xsi:type="string">positions:list-secondary</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="catalogsearch.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
            <block name="search.search_terms_log" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::search_terms_log.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="search_terms_log" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchTermsLog</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <referenceBlock name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can you share your XML file path, file name and the XML code please.

Comment: Your path seem to be wrong `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding below code to `catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

> app⁩/design/⁨frontend/⁨theme/⁨Default/Magento_CatalogSearch⁩/⁨layout⁩/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    ......
    //Your other xml
    ......
</page>
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Getting a blank site/error.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in proper location.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="search.result" template="result.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="product/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- If argument's position depends on image size changeable in VDE:
                        positions:list-secondary,grid-secondary,list-actions,grid-actions,list-primary,grid-primary
                    -->
                        <argument name="positioned" xsi:type="string">positions:list-secondary</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="product/list/toolbar.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="catalogsearch.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="search.result">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Search Results</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Problem solved. It was a 3rd party extension (MegaMenu). There was another catalogsearch_result_index.xml which overrides my changes.